# How do I get the product attribute Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart

Tags: magento

I need this in Cart model.

If you go in `Checkout/Model/Cart.php` there is a function `updateItems` I want to do something here with `Minimum Qty Allowed` attribute value of product.

How do I get this value here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this example, taken directly from `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart`:

```
$minimumQty = $product->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty();
```

The stock system is a bit obtuse, I'm not surprised it was hard to find. Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe